# Sencha touch 2 Event listeners in Ext.Define

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I was reading the sencha docs about Event handling and the listeners config. 
In the documentation of [the listener config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-listeners) I found this note :

> Note: It is bad practice to specify a listener's config when you are defining a class using Ext.define(). Instead, only specify listeners when you are instantiating your class with Ext.create().

I have seen a number of S.O. answers which have **listeners** in the `Ext.define()`.

Also I came accross this blog post about [the evils of Ext.define and listeners](https://web.archive.org/web/20120517040029/http://mitchellsimoens.com/2011/12/ext-js-4/ext-define-and-listeners-as-a-property-bad/) but i think this is *more relevant* to Ext-Js than to Sencha Touch 2. And I am fairly new to Sencha Touch.

Can anyone explain the difference cons of adding listeners in the Ext.define() and what difference does it make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is pretty basic. If you have a `listener` property in your class, the moment you create an instance of the class and add a *`listener` property* to that particular instance, it is gong to override the Ext.define 's listener property. Just like this:

```
var obj = {
  foo: {
     bar : 'Hello World'
  }
};

obj = Ext.merge(obj, { // Here Ext.merge just to show how two objects can be merged
  foo : 'I just got changed!'
});
```

Will you get the `bar` property of `foo` object? No. Identical properties get overridden. Similar things happen for listeners too.

```
Ext.define('ABC', {
  config : {
    listeners : {
      'tap' : Ext.emptyFn
    } 
  }
});    

var newPanel = Ext.create('ABC', {
  listeners : {
      'activate' : Ext.emptyFn
  } 
});
```

The config object you pass in `Ext.create` is merged with the config object of `Ext.define`. So, its always a better choice not to use `listener` property in `Ext.define`.

Comment: But if i had defined all my listeners ONLY in `Ext.define` (and had no listeners in Ext.create) then the merge wouldn't override the listeners config and I would STILL have the listeners right?

Comment: Yes, then there is no problem. But why would you want to inject something like that? Rather use Simeons's option to add the listener with on() method inside the initialize function and you will get everything.

Comment: @Swar I am Sencha touch beginner. what is `Simeons's option to add the listener with on()`?

Comment: The link is given in the question: "the evils of Ext.define and listeners"